# How to limit number of downloads from Firebase Storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

As far as I can see there are no security rules in the Firebase Storage that could limit the number of downloads per user.

I can limit the file size or number of files for writes with a simple trick like this:

```
  match /public/{userId}/{imageId} {
  allow write: if request.resource.size < 5 * 1024 * 1024 && 
  imageId.matches("[1-5]\.txt");
}
```

And according to [Google Quotas & Limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas):

> There is an update limit on each object of once per second, so rapid writes to a single object won’t scale.

So this is great but **how to prevent too many reads once a download link is known to a malicious user?** This is especially important for security as again according to [Google Quotas & Limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas):

> There is no limit to reads of an object. Buckets initially support roughly 5000 reads per second and then scale as needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no configuration for limiting the volume of downloads for files stored in Cloud Storage.  If a user has access to read any data at all, they can read it as much as they want.  There is no accounting related to the amount of per-user data consumed, or number of times a file is accessed.  There are no security rule that let you restrict access in this way.  There are no Cloud Functions triggers that let you do the accounting yourself.

The documentation for limits on uploads is not related to what you're trying to do.  The limits on scalability have only to do with the performance of the underlying system, not the permissions of the end users.

If you want to limit what end users can do, you will need to route them through some middleware component that you build that tracks how they're using your provided API to download files, and restrict what they can do based on their prior behavior.  This is obviously nontrivial to implement, but it's possible.

Comment: Thank you a lot for clarification. So am I exaggerating and this is really not a security issue? I am just worried that it may be very easy for someone to use a lot of the transfer and raise our bills. On the other hand I know there are many companies using Firebase Storage without any issues.

Comment: Yes, it's a billing issue, not a security issue. You are always free to file a feature request, but I suspect that might not be a priority for the firebase team.

Comment: What about the Google Cloud Storage JSON API limit settings in the Google Cloud Platform? I can change the "Queries per 100 seconds per user" limit and I am wondering If I can use it to limit number of downloads/writes per end user this way. Are these setting affecting the Firebase Storage?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: Thank you so much Doug for your time. It is hard for me to believe Google is not giving us any way to block or limit malicious users from downloading a lot of data/files and raising our bills. I consider it a security issue for us when anybody can easily make our costs unpredictable. It is a pity we have to look for workarounds or other solutions. I will definitely file a feature request.

Comment: This is a problem with pretty much any public API endpoint.  I doubt you'll see resolution on this any time soon.  If you wan to control access to resource in your project, you should do that through Cloud Functions and some accounting system you implement on your own.

Comment: @DougStevenson As I understand it, if we were to use cloud functions as the middleware to do some accounting, we would need to download the file to the ephemeral Node instance, then send the file from the cloud function to the user? Wouldn't this be really inefficient, since the download becomes delayed for the user, and this would also increase billing for cloud function bandwidth? Is there a better way to do this?