# How can I enforce rate limit for users downloading from Google Cloud Storage bucket?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am implementing a dictionary website using App Engine and Cloud Storage. App Engine controls the backend, like user authentication etc., and Cloud Storage is used to store a JSON file for each dictionary entry.

I would like to rate limit how much a user can download in a given time period so they can't bulk download the JSON files and result in a big charge for me. Ideally, the dictionary would display a captcha if a user downloads too much at once, and allow them to keep downloading if they pass the captcha. What is the best way to achieve this?

Is there a specific service for rate limiting based on IP address or authenticated user? Should I do this through App Engine and only access Cloud Storage through App Engine (perhaps slower since it's using some of my dynamic resources to serve static content)? Or is it possible to have the frontend access Cloud Storage and implement the rate limiting on Cloud Storage directly? Is a Cloud bucket the right service for storage, here? And how can I allow search engine indexing bots to bypass the rate limiting?

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Doug Stevenson in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54029942/11928130)

> "There is no configuration for limiting the volume of downloads for
>   files stored in Cloud Storage."

and explaining further:

> "If you want to limit what end users can do, you will need to route
>   them through some middleware component that you build that tracks how
>   they're using your provided API to download files, and restrict what
>   they can do based on their prior behavior. This is obviously
>   nontrivial to implement, but it's possible."

Comment: Thanks, yeah it sounds like what I need is something like Cloud Endpoints